# Find a match of certain columns from the first datatable in the second

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two `DataTables`: *dtChild* and *dtMaster*.
[image]

For every row in *dtChild*, I would like to see if there is a match in *dtMaster*. And this matching is based on specific columns.

So in the image above, both `DataTables` have columns named *Col2* and *Col3*. And these are columns we are interested in. In the second row, we have a match. Because there is a row in *dtMaster* with the value of *Col2* equal to *Value22* and value of *Col3* equal to *Value23*.

I want to write a LINQ query that returns `null` for the first row result (since there is no match for the first tow in *dtChild*) and for the second row returns the id of the found record in *dtMaster* (let's assume *dtMaster* also has a Primary Key column called Id in this case).

**N.B. The column names can vary every time we run the program. So we would like our LINQ to be dynamic. Also the number of matching columns (2 in the example above) can vary. So there might be a case where our condition is based on the value of 5 columns.**

Comment: What if there are multiple matches? Do you want the id (i assume `Col1`) of the first match only?

Comment: There is something very wrong in your logic "For every row in dtChild, I would like to see if there is a match in dtMaster". The point of master/child relationship is that a row in master always exists while child may or may not exist, not the opposite

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good question. We only care about the first match. We'd like the match to return to the value of column called `Id` which will be a fixed name unlike others.

Comment: @MladenOršolić this is not a master-child relationship. We just would like to update the `dtMaster `based on the values in `dtChild`. Let's forget about the semantics of master and child.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
DataTable dtResult = dtChild.Clone();
foreach(DataRow row in dtChild.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = dtResult.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField("Col1", row.Field<string>("Col1"));
    DataRow firstmatchingRow = dtMaster.AsEnumerable()
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Col2") == row.Field<string>("Col2")
                          && r.Field<string>("Col3") == row.Field<string>("Col3"));
    string col2 = null;
    string col3 = null;
    if(firstmatchingRow != null)
    {
        col2 = firstmatchingRow.Field<string>("Col2");
        col3 = firstmatchingRow.Field<string>("Col3");
    }
    newRow.SetField("Col2", col2);
    newRow.SetField("Col3", col3);
}
```

If you want a dynamic approach where you can specify the key-columns of both tables you could use this:

```
string[] keyColumnNames = { "Col2", "Col3" };
DataTable dtResult = dtChild.Clone();

DataColumn[] childColumns = dtResult.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
    .Where(c => keyColumnNames.Contains(c.ColumnName)) 
    .ToArray();
DataColumn[] masterColumns = dtMaster.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
    .Where(c => keyColumnNames.Contains(c.ColumnName)) 
    .ToArray();

foreach (DataRow row in dtChild.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = dtResult.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField("Col1", row.Field<string>("Col1"));
    var matchingRows = dtMaster.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(masterRow => !masterColumns.Select(mc => masterRow.Field<string>(mc))
            .Except(childColumns.Select(cc => row.Field<string>(cc)))
            .Any());
    DataRow firstMatchingRow = matchingRows.FirstOrDefault();
    foreach(DataColumn col in childColumns)
        newRow.SetField(col, firstMatchingRow == null 
            ? null 
            : firstMatchingRow.Field<string>(col.ColumnName));
}
```

Comment: The column names can vary every time we run the program. So we would like our LINQ to be dynamic. Also the number of matching columns (2 in the example above) can vary. So there might be a case where our condition is based on the value of 5 columns.

Comment: @Pedram: have a look.

Comment: I'm gonna try the second solution. Will come back. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so why are we setting the value of `Col1` in dtChild? Let's assume dtMaster has a column named Id and if there is a match, we would like the query to return the first match's Id value and nothing more. dtChild may or may not have a Col1.

Comment: @Pedram: i thought that you wanted to find every match of dtChild in dtMaster. That's why i loop dtChild. You need to identify every record, i have presumed that `Col1` is the key column of `dtChild`. If you only want the first matches ID column (i assume `Col1` of `dtMaster`) modify the code after `DataRow firstMatchingRow` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested...

```
class Data<T>()
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public T Value{get; set;}
}

var cols=dtChild.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().All(c=>c.Name).toList();
var idCol=cols.Single(c=>c=="Id");
var valcols=cols.Where(c=>c!="Id");

var lst=new List<Data>();
var chlds=dtChild.Rows.OfType(DataRow);
chlds.ToList().ForEach(c=>lst.Add(new Data{ Id=c[idCol], Value=null} ); //initialize to null

foreach(var r1 in chlds)
{
  foreach(var r2 in dtMaster.Rows.OfType(DataRow))
  {
    if (r1[idcol]==r2[idCol])
    {
       forech(var c in valCols)
       {
        if (r1[c]==r2[c])
        {
          lst.Single(l=>l.Id==r1[c]).Value= r2[idCol];
          break;
        }
       }
    }
  }
}
```